# How to get geolocation from another file?

Tags: javascript, express, import, geolocation

This is the all repo:

[repo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/twilight-worker-qx9m5f?file=%2Fpublic%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A16%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A333%2C%22startColumn%22%3A16%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A333%7D%5D)

After installing it it create html website like this: [website](https://qx9m5f-3000.csb.app/)

In the script.js there is a code:

```
        if (update) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                userLocationSuccess =>
                    resolveAdress(userLocationSuccess, update),
                showError,
                options
            );
        } else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                resolveAdress,
                showError,
                options
            );
        }

 
This code takes the geolocation from resolveAdress which is in a different folder to get geolocation. (The "script.js" import resolveAdress from the routes/API/resolveAdress.js file) 

In the app.js file there is a part of code which imports require data:  weatherAPI, suggestionsAPI and resolveadressAPI.

I got a question: How to make it that all the website will be in html  format? I would like to import all data from weatherAPI, suggestionsAPI and resolveadressAPI and will be placed in api.js file which is in folder: public/js/ 

Is it possible to make html website which import all data without installing it for example on vercel.app or nelify.app?

I am not sure if you know want I mean my English is poor.

Thank you
```

Comment: Do you have any issues with the current folder structure ? It seem like your goal is to stuff up all your code into a single file and have a messy file as a result on the end ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I added new explanation.